# How can I use an object to mark on another object?

Tags: materials

So I'm making a lightsaber and I want to know how I can make it leave a trail of molten-metal type stuff on another object. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: This sounds like a classic application for [Dynamic Paint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/dynamic_paint/introduction.html). Its output could be used to mask between materials, create displacements, etc.